# Export Plone users to LDAP?

Tags: svn, ldap, plone

I've been tasked with setting up a subversion server next to a Plone instance. The situation is that the Plone instance is already in a "production" state because there are outside users that can access it any moment.

I believe setting up a LDAP and binding both, the Plone and subversion instance, to it for authentication is the best solution.

So, my question is 
*"how do I export already existing users and respective credentials from a Plone instance to an LDAP install for a seamless transition?"*

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "one-step" Plone-to-LDAP export tool, you'll have to export your Plone users to CSV, and then import your users to your LDAP database.

Tools for Plone that can export members to CSV include:

ArcheCSV

atreal.usersinout